# Setting watcher on multiple attributes of directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes, angularjs-scope

I am trying to set common watcher on more than one attributes in a directive. My code is as follows

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch(function () {
                    return [attrs.attrOne];
                }, function (newVal) {
                   console.log(newVal);
                }, true);

    })
```

but this doesn't work, I have already set the third parameter for object equality as true. However if I try to set watcher on just single attribute it works fine and the code is as shown below

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
               $scope.$watch(attrs.attrOne,
               function (newVal) {
                 console.log(newVal);
                });
        });
```

Can anyone explain this in details, why is this behavior happening?

Comment: @georgeawg, in the plunk why did you pass x as attr-one="{{x}}" why not attr-one="x", is there any specific reason for curly brackets here

Answer (score 0):

Starting from AngularJS 1.3 there's a new method called $watchGroup for observing a set of expressions.

```
$scope.foo = 'foo';
$scope.bar = 'bar';

$scope.$watchGroup(['foo', 'bar'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
  // newValues array contains the current values of the watch expressions
  // with the indexes matching those of the watchExpression array
  // i.e.
  // newValues[0] -> $scope.foo 
  // and 
  // newValues[1] -> $scope.bar 
});
```

Comment: problem is that I am on 1.0.8 so this is not available to me for use